# remotebuild test failing with ENOTFOUND

Tags: taco

After installing remotebuild (and checking dependencies), I tried a

```
remotebuild test.
```

It fails with a

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Any ideas if I'm missing something?

Comment: Hey there - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered issues with remote build and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your mac have an incorrect hostname? If you open up node and run `os.hostname()` does that give a name which corresponds to the machine? If you do not explicitly specify a hostname in the options, then we try and use `os.hostname()` as "the name the rest of the network thinks I am" for generating HTTPS certificates and for running the self test. Sometimes macs pick the wrong name or the DNS entry gets changed so it no longer refers to the correct machine, and that may cause this error.

If that is the case, you can run `remotebuild --hostname="correct.example.com" saveconfig` to generate a configuration file with the manually-corrected hostname (or IP address) and try re-running the test. You may need to run `remotebuild certificates reset` after changing the hostname configuration because the hostname is part of the certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Just an update that might help other people: My problem wasn't exact on the os.hostname. That was returning the correct value. Problem was actually that my mac wasn't correctly resolving the hostname. I added it to /etc/hosts for testing and it worked fine.